# how to delete a scenario in atg through API methods

Tags: atg

I have created a scenario by creating a `myScenario.sdl` in my local config folder `/atg/registry/data/scenarios/myScenario.sdl`

**myScenario.sdl**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE process SYSTEM "dynamosystemresource:/atg/dtds/pdl/pdl_1.0.dtd">
<process author="admin" creation-time="1413804041263" enabled="false" last-modified-by="admin" modification-time="1413804191188">
  <segment migrate-subjects="true">
    <segment-name>ItemAddedToOrder</segment-name>
    <!--================================-->
    <!--== Item added to order Quantity with fraction is defined  -->
    <!--================================-->
    <event id="1">
      <event-name>atg.commerce.order.ItemAddedToOrder</event-name>
      <filter construct="event-property-filter" operator="isNotNull">
        <event-property construct="event-property">
          <property-name>quantityWithFraction</property-name>
        </event-property>
      </filter>
    </event>
    <!--================================-->
    <!--== Log a message message: Quantity With Fraction is Defines logTriggeringEvent: true  -->
    <!--================================-->
    <action id="2">
      <action-name>Log a message</action-name>
      <action-param name="message">
        <constant>Quantity With Fraction is Defines</constant>
      </action-param>
      <action-param name="logTriggeringEvent">
        <constant type="java.lang.Boolean">true</constant>
      </action-param>
    </action>
  </segment>
</process>
```

And enabled the scenario:

```
    Registry scenarioRegistry = scenarioManager.getScenarioRegistry();
    byte[] data = (byte[]) scenarioRegistry.getItem(pScenarioPath);
    String xml = null;

    if (data != null) {
        xml = new String(data, "UTF-8");
    } else {
        Assert.fail("No scenario is existed to enable/disable");
    }
    String updatedXml;
    if (scenarioState && xml != null) {
        updatedXml = xml.replaceAll("enabled=\"false\"", "enabled=\"true\"");
    } else {
        updatedXml = xml.replaceAll("enabled=\"true\"", "enabled=\"false\"");

    }

    scenarioRegistry.putItem(pScenarioPath, updatedXml.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

Now with this above written code, I can both disable or enable the scenario by changing the state as false and true respectively. But I want to delete the scenario(please remember, my requirement is DELETE not DISABLE SCENARIO). I know using `scenarioManager.updateScenario()` deleted the scenario. Is my understanding right?

One more thing, I know I can delete the scenario directly from ACC. But I need to code via code not manually from ACC.

Please share your thoughts!

Comment: It would be good to give a reason for downvote...

Answer (score 0):

Did you try scenarioRegistry.removeItem(path);